# How to sort values by letters, numbers, characters in SQL?

Tags: sql-order-by

I have a 'name' column in table that contains for example:
**name:**
*ab.xy
ab2g
ab*
when I order the table by name column, I get as result:
**name:**
*ab
ab.xy
ab2g*
but I want the result to be:
**name:**
*ab
ab2g
ab.xy*

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no easy way to do what you want.
sql sorts by (simply said) ascii-value. And the "." has a lower Ascii-Value than all the letters. Also keep in mind that all uppercase letters are sorted in before lowercase letters.

If you need to sort like this, I'd advise to create a redundant column with the values normalized (i.e. all lowercase, certain chars removed) that helsps with your sorting. This way you can index that helper column and don't lose a lot of performance with bigger queries.

Comment: about the upper-lower case, i ignored that using lower() casting.
now my problem is how to move up the numbers before the charcters